# Audio distortion when on Zoom or Skype

Tags: zoom-meeting

When on Zoom (or Skype) with folk in America, there is constant audio distortion, bought ne UPS headset, still the same problem. What to do?

Comment: You've provided no clear specifics; what Ubuntu product are you using? what release of that product? what package type you installed & are using (ie. how did you install it) etc.

Comment: Try turning down the volume on the microphone.

Comment: Why is the system not recognizing my USB headset? How to determine at the system level the recognized USB headset?